# autofs shall mount depending on network/address

Tags: networking, automounting, autofs

when I use my notebook not in my office network, the auto mounter should not try to mount my /etc/auto.share entries.
Is there a setting avoiding the mount depending on the network/address?

The big drawback, if the automounter tries the mount, is that some applications try to resolve (automount) pathes (recent files), and the application hangs in very long timeouts.

I am using FC32.

Regards
Rainer

Answer (score 0):

When you're out of the office, just stop the **autofs** service:

```
sudo systemctl stop autofs
```

This will not disable the service, so when you reboot at the office, **autofs** will be working again.